# Every hour reach entry processes limit on shared hosting

Tags: cpanel, linux

We are on a shared hosting and from today (we didn't change anything), every beginning hour the website just go away and it's unreachable for 4-5 min. The cPanel says we have reached the Entry Processes Limit.

We don't have any cron jobs. If I open up the [htop](https://htop.dev) terminal when the website is down, it has many LSPHP processes.

My questions are:

- What does "reached the Entry Processes Limit" mean?
- How can I list all the processes in the terminal?

Version: Linux version 3.10.0

Comment: "ps waux" should list all the processes on a Linux box.

Comment: BTW, I suspect you are Running a version of Redhat or CentOS7 - noth Linux 3.10.0.

Answer (score 2):

From my research, this issue happens because you have some long-running processes that have filled all the available Apache resources.

A way to find which may be bottling down your server, try:

```
ps --sort etime -A -o etime,pid,user,args | grep php | grep -vE 'php-fpm|\-\-mode daemon|grep'
```

The 1st number shows the running or elapsed time. You'll need to look on that list and kill the culprit(s).

Afterward, it would be best to look at the originating script to find out why it's not finishing its tasks or why it's taking so long to do so.